# iPad mini 2 settings for local MCPE (0.12.1) server

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, ios

My son and I have a problem creating and joining a local MCPE (0.12.1) server with his new iPad mini 2 (iOS 8.4.1 (12H321)).
I know this might be a tough one to "break" - Cause there's A LOT of settings to poke around with on the iPad.

I have an old iPad 1 (OS 5.1.1 (9B206)) and a Samsung Galaxy Tab (don't know which one) both tablets have MCPE 0.12.1 installed.
These two tabs have no problem creating/hosting/joining a local server - But the Mini can't see or join a server created with the above tablets. But! sometimes we're able to get it to show and join/host a server right after it has been rebooted - But after a minute or two it disconnects.

Wifi signal is very good - "Local Server Multiplayer" is enabled on all tablets - We're also using the correct IP's/ports.

Therefore I think it has to do with some of the settings on the Mini.

So the question is: Which settings is NEEDED AS A MINIMUM to be enabled/disabled on the Mini to be able to host/join a local MCPE (0.12.1) server??

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug people have been reporting. Check here:
https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MCPE-10604

Comment: I will copy my post to the Mojang site. Maybe it's helpful to someone...